# Relative homology and deformation retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was reading Hatcher's, and I thought of something that should be obvious but had difficulty proving it.

Suppose X is a topological space, and $A \in X$ and $A$ deformation retracts to $A'$. I would think $H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(X,A')$ for all $n$.

I tried to prove $(X,A)$ and $(X,A')$ are homotopy equivalent. However, although the deformation retraction shows the identity $id: A \rightarrow A$ and the retraction $r: A \rightarrow A'$ are homotopic, I would need to extend the definition on $X$ so that it would be continuous.

Can some one please help me to see if the statement is true, and possibly give a proof or counterexample?

Comment: Everybody deserves his name to be spelled correctly. That is why I edited your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his answer user989600 has given the crucial hint: Use the long exact sequences of pairs. Let me add *plus the five lemma*.

In fact, the following is true:

> Lemma : Let $f : (Y,B) \to (Z,C)$ be a map of pairs such that $f : Y \to Z$ and $f \mid_B : B \to C$ are homotopy equivalences. Then $f_* : H_n(Y,B) \to H_n(Z,C)$ is an isomorphism for all $n$.

To prove it, consider

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(B)   @>>> H_n(Y) @>>> H_n(Y,B) @>>> H_{n-1}(B) @>>> H_{n-1}(Y) \\
@V{(f \mid_B )_*}VV @V{f_*}VV  @V{f_*}VV @V{(f \mid_B )_*}VV  @V{f_*}VV \\
H_n(C)   @>>> H_n(Z) @>>> H_n(Z,C) @>>> H_{n-1}(C) @>>> H_{n-1}(Z) \end{CD}

The vertical arrows at positions $1, 2, 4, 5$ are isomorphisms, thus the five lemma applies.

The identity map $id  : X \to X$ gives us a map of pairs $id : (X,A' ) \to (X,A)$ as in the above lemma. Note that all what is needed is that $A' \hookrightarrow A$ is a homotopy equivalence which is a weaker requirement than in your question.

Comment: I knew that if there is a homotopy euivalence between $(X,A')$ and $(X,A)$, then we are done. The direction from $(X,A')$ to $(X,A)$ is simple, as we can use the identity map as you mentioned. However, I find no guarantee that even if $A$ deformation retracts onto $A'$, there exists a corresponding continuous map from $X$ to $X$ that sends $A$ to $A'$ that satisfies the requirements. The deformation retraction is only defined on $A$, and we now need to expand that to all of $X$. What you mentioned brought me much delight, but I am still not sure if the statement in the problem is true or not.

Comment: @Frank It is true. If $A$ deformation retracts to $A'$, then the inclusion $i : A' \hookrightarrow A$ is a homotopy equivalence. The identity $id_X$ restricts to $i$ on $A'$, i.e. is a map of pairs $id_X : (X,A') \to (X,A)$ to which my answer applies. We do  not have a map of pairs $f : (X,A) \to (X,A')$ which restricts  to a retraction $r : A \to A'$ - but we do not need such a map.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking something basic. I always thought homotopy equivalence requires two maps $f,g$ such that $f:(X,A') \rightarrow (X,A), g:(X,A) \rightarrow (X,A')$ and $f \circ g \simeq id, g \circ f \simeq id$. Of course, we can omit $g$ if it obviously exists. Why do we need only one map? What definition did you use?

Comment: @Frank You require that $(X,A)$ and $(X,A')$ are homotopy equivalent *as pairs*. In my answer I work with a map of pairs $f : (X,A') \to (X,A)$ which is **not required** to be a homotopy equivalence of pairs. Only the "absolute part" $f : X \to X$ and the "relative part" $f \mid_{A'}: A' \to A$ are required to be ordinary homotopy equivalences of spaces. This is much weaker than being a homotopy equivalence of pairs. See user989600's answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true that $(X, A)$ and $(X, A')$ need be homotopy equivalent, even if $A'$ deformation retracts to $A$. Consider $X = S^1$ and $A = \{1\}$ vs $A' = S^1 \setminus \{-1\}$: the only map $(S^1, A') \to (S^1, A)$ is the constant map sending everything to $1$. These pairs are not homotopy equivalent.

Instead, think about the induced map between long exact sequences of pairs.

Comment: can you please say some more? I also tried long exact sequences of triples. I am not too sure how the induced map between $(X,A)$ and $(X,A')$ would work out, assuming you meant induced by inclusion $i: (X,A') \rightarrow (X,A)$.